# Onclick function is not working when i use GET variable to pass data to another page using php

Tags: javascript, php, get

Why is my onclick function is not working when i entered a page that has GET variable?

I have a simple onclick javascript function on my page button which is to show the custom modal i created, and it's working fine unless i entered to a page i made that has GET variable such as:

```
http://mywebsite.com/page3.php?variable=45
```

Let me show you my simple onclick function if there's an error.

```js
function customShow() {
  document.getElementById("cusModal").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="customShow()">Show Modal</button>
```

Those code is working fine if i'm only at the page that has not GET variable such as:

```
http://mywebsite.com/page2.php
```

I know i can fix this using SESSION for variable that need to pass data to another page, but i wanted ask some help here if there's a possible way to make the onclick funtion work?

Comment: What is it that makes you think that a "GET variable" (whatever that means) is affecting your "click" handler?

Comment: @Pointy Yeah! if i'm only on the page that has url like this `http://mywebsite.com/page2.php` onclick function is working fine, but if i enter a page that has a url something like this `http://mywebsite.com/page3.php?variable=45` onclick funtion is not working anymore

Comment: I'm sorry, but that does not make any sense. Without seeing more code however I can't help further.

Answer (score 0):

You may have something like below inside your customShow function which prevents default action.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Thankyou! but still not working. I'm already at the page that has the url like this `http://mywebsite.com/page3.php?variable=45`
The button is not clickable